# Determining whether file is compiled (in exe')or not in matlab

Tags: matlab, exe, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

So I have a piece of MATLAB code which I am compiling in exe. This exe file is to be used by people who don't have MATLAB installed. But the original m file is also in use by some advanced users. There are some features that I can't provide in the compiled exe version.  My problem is that I want to maintain the same code for both exe and the m original. In order to do that, I want my code to automatically detect whether the running file is exe or an m file so that I can disable some function for the exe version simply with an if statement. Is there is way to do this???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [isdeployed](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/isdeployed.html) function